# Click two new points and draw a line between those two points using mouse event

Tags: c#, events, graphics, gdi+

Any suggestions how to create a line by clicking two new points then draw a line between them?
I am trying to create a distance tool like the one in adobe acrobat.

Image Example

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem Solved!**

**EDIT:**
Here's the code:

```
private Point p1, p2;
List<Point> p1List = new List<Point>();
List<Point> p2List = new List<Point>();

    private void Panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (p1.X == 0)
        {
            p1.X = e.X;
            p1.Y = e.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            p2.X = e.X;
            p2.Y = e.Y;

            p1List.Add(p1);
            p2List.Add(p2);

            Invalidate();
            p1.X = 0;
        }
    }

    private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using(var p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 4))
        {
            for(int x = 0; x<p1List.Count; x++){
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, p1List[x], p2List[x]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Panel1.CreateGraphics()`, you should instead use the panel's `OnPaint` method.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky that example is on a MouseDown() event.

Comment: I know that. What you *should* be doing is "when the mouse moves, set the position of your objects" so this means that you move points, lines, shapes, whatever. Then at the *end* of that method you call `Refresh()` to for the control to re-draw. The paint method is handled by `OnPaint()`. *This* is where (OnPaint) you *draw* everything. You take current positions and draw them. Take a look at my answer from the other post to see what I mean. You should *never* need to call `CreateGraphics()` during an event if you're painting *on* the control.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the mouse click event on the panel (for example) and retrieve the location of the click (using the event args). Store this location in an attribute. Do that for as many points as you need.
In the panel paint event, call the parent paint, then draw the lines between your points.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
Point firstPoint;
Point seondPoint;

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.firstPoint == null) {
        this.firstPoint = e.Location;
    }

    if (this.secondPoint == null) {
        this.secondPoint = e.Location;
    }

    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void panel1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{       
    Using (pn as new Pen(Color.Blue, 5))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pn, firstPoint, secondPoint);
    }
}
```

EDIT: You also dont need to do `CreateGraphics` to draw the line - in the Paint event you have a graphics object already.

Comment: This code is just telling me to draw a line from point a to point b.

Comment: Which is what first line in your question asks for?

Comment: As you can see from the code I draw two lines there. I want the first line to be one Point then the second line as well. After that I want to connect them together to create a real line.
Are you using Adobe PDF Reader? if so, try to look at it's distance tool feature.